# Exposing common Properties to an MVC Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In MyMainView I have multiple PartialViews.

Each PartialView is strongly typed to a property exposed in MyMainView and each partial view also contains some common information.

eg

```
public class MainModel
{
    public SubModel1 { get; set; }
    public SubModel2 { get; set; }
    public SubModel3 { get; set; }
    public CommonStuff { get; set; }
}
```

Is there an accepted practice for achieving the sharing of this Common property?

I was thinking of having a property in the SubModel that reffered back to its parent. Is this recommended/not recommended?

eg.

```
public class SubModel1
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public MainModel ParentModel { get; set; }
}
```

Main goal here is to avoid loading up the same data over and over again.

For the model I am currently looking at, its a series of LookUp dictionaries that are shared across the View, and used in things like drop down lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [post](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/when-to-use-html-renderpartial-and-html-renderaction-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/) will help you to solve the confusion.

In your case mostly you may have to query the complete model in the main action and feed it to the main view. From the main view pass the main model to the partial views that depends upon both the sub model as well as the common properties using `Html.RenderPartial` or only the sub models to the partial views those needs only that.

You should use child actions if you are displaying a sub model in a partial view and that **partial view doesn't depends upon the main model**, simply *the partial view is completely independent of the main view*.

You can also go for child actions suppose you need apply caching behavior for a particular section.

You can avoid child actions suppose you want to display the same model in two or more partial views in the same view, because you have to query the data again and again.

So the solution is you should judiciously choose child actions or Html.RenderPartials based upon the above comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could use child actions. Phil Haack [blogged](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) about them. This way you could encapsulate the entire common functionality into a separate Model/Controller/View lifecycle which is distinct from the main one and embed it as a widget.